# Edit Application Menu in Fedora 16 XFCE?

Tags: fedora, xfce, application

I am running a fully updated Fedora 16 with XFCE in my VirtualBox virtual machine, and just like to know how I can edit the items in its Application Menu?

Update: I installed the program alacarte, but it refuses to start with this error:

```
MainWindow.py:19:<module>:ImportError: No module named gmenu
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I usually just create custom launchers on the panel and drap-drop those menu items to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xfce 4.8 menus can be edited with a program named `alacarte`. lxde's `lxmed` can edit xfce menus also, i've never used it before so i personally can't vouch for it.

Comment: I installed alacarte, but it doesn't start, and have me this error "MainWindow.py:19:<module>:ImportError: No module named gmenu", what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: hm, seems alacarte is having api problems. bug report on it here if interested: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=734442
 lxmed is another program that can edit xfce4.8 menus and seems to be recommended in the xfce wiki.